# remove property name from js, after mapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

How to remove property name from returned value? I need to remove the property name projects: [ ] from output.

```
router.get("/",  (req, res, next) => {
Project.find()
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        res.status(200).json({
            projects: docs.map(doc => {
                return {
                    name: doc.name,
                    description: doc.description,
                    };
            })
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
```

});

the output i m getting now is :

```
{
    "projects": [
        {
            "name": "before",
            "description": "el 
}
]    
}
```

I need to remove the property name "projects" from output.

Comment: Do you want the value of the projects, or do you want to remove the property and its value?

Comment: What do you mean by remove the property name "projects" ? if you want only array in output then change res.status(200).json(docs.map(doc => { return {name: doc.name,description: doc.description,};})) and if you want tot delete the property use delete output["projects"]

Comment: Why include it in the first place?

Comment: In hurry, i forgot to remove braces from res.status(200).json({}).  thank you so much guys. My bad. it was  a completely silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the projects property and directly return what the map function returns

```
res.status(200).json(
         docs.map(doc => {
            return {
                name: doc.name,
                description: doc.description,
                };})
               )
```

Comment: In hurry, i forgot to remove braces from res.status(200).json({}).  thank you so much @jazib.

Comment: happy to help.. :)